# Alphabet "pagination" check if there are records for each letter

Tags: php, mysql

I want to be able to create an alphabet pagination of some sort, where you have A-Z and each have a link to filter by letter, however, I want to be able to label the letters with a background indicating that there are records that starts with the letter.

It looks like this so far, showing labelled letters:

[image]

On another thing, I'm using pagination for the results which is obviously using `LIMIT` on the query, so I cannot use `SUBSTRING` on the column then lay them out with the letters, I was wondering if it's possible to do it in one query while the search picks out the records with the records that starts with the letter.

I need to be able to *show* the letters that has the filled background, indicating that there is **at least** one record per letter, if there isn't any records to a letter, it shouldn't show the filled background.

Is it possible to do this; within one query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was wondering if it's possible to do it in one query

The wish of having **everything** in just one query makes no sense. Each query should do one and just one particular piece of work.

So your script obviously consists of 2 parts for now:

1. Retrieve a set of records paginated by `LIMIT`
2. Retrieve the distinct list of first letters

So perform 2 *different* queries.